# Can't turn off requirehttps in asp.net 5 MVC 6 site

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an asp.net 5 MVC 6 site I am working on. I turned on require HTTPS like so:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
});
```

It worked great, and I have been working like this for a little while. Today I need to turn it off, so I commented out the options filter, but it is still requiring HTTPS.

I have not used the [RequireHttps] attribute on the controllers or actions themselves.

I have gone into the properties and unchecked "Enable SSL" and pasted the http url in the "Launch URL" box.

I have shutdown IIS Express and relaunched the site. It doesn't seem to matter what I do, it continues to try to redirect to HTTPS.

Is it possible IIS Express or Kestral has cached something I need to delete?
Anyone have any suggestions of what else could be forcing it to HTTPS?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`RequireHttpsAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/RequireHttpsAttribute.cs#L47) implementation will send a permanent redirect response (301) back to browser:

```
// redirect to HTTPS version of page
filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(newUrl, permanent: true);
```

This means that when you initially had the attribute enabled and requested a url like http://localhost:62058/, the server will respond with:

```
301 (Moved permanently)
Location: https://localhost:62058/
```

If you look at the [definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) of the 301 response code you will see that browsers will cache it by default:

> The requested resource has been assigned a new permanent URI and any
>   future references to this resource SHOULD use one of the returned
>   URIs. Clients with link editing capabilities ought to automatically
>   re-link references to the Request-URI to one or more of the new
>   references returned by the server, where possible. **This response is
>   cacheable unless indicated otherwise**.
>
> The new permanent URI SHOULD be given by the Location field in the
>   response. Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the
>   response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the
>   new URI(s).

After you remove the `RequireHttps` filter, the browser will still use the cached response:

[image: Getting cached redirect to https response]

So all you need to do after removing the `RequireHttps` filter is **rebuild and clear the browser cache!**

Comment: Oh don't I feel foolish. Daniel, thank you for a well written and detailed answer!